# How to add colorbar to image ('AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'colorbar')

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5

I would like to know how to add colorbar and show it in app

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pylab as plt    
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *    
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (
    FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas,
    NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets 

# test is wafermap
test = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,101), columns=range(0,101))     
for i in range(0,101):
    for j in range(0,101):
        if ((50-i)**2 + (50-j)**2) < 50**2:
            test.loc[i,j] = i*2+i+j
        else:
            test.loc[i,j] = 0
test[test == 0] = np.nan  

Ui_MainWindow, QMainWindow = loadUiType(r'C:\Users\wtjang\Wafer viewer\test_file_open.ui')


class Main(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, ):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color : white;")  


    def addmpl(self, fig):
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
        self.mplvl.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.draw()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

    fig1 = Figure()

    ax1f1 = fig1.add_subplot(111) 
    ax1f1.imshow(test, interpolation = 'hanning', vmin = 0, cmap = 'gist_rainbow_r')

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.addmpl(fig1)

    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I got a below output

[image]

But I would like to get below image. In other words, I would like to add colorbar.

[image]

So I tried to add colorbar. But I failed....

```
ax1f1.imshow(test, interpolation = 'hanning', vmin = 0, cmap = 'gist_rainbow_r')
ax1f1.colorbar()
```

I got an error

```
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'colorbar'
```

How can I get it?

Comment: Try 'fig1.colorbar()' instead. Did it work?

Comment: change `ax1f1.imshow(test, ...')` to `img = ax1f1.imshow(test, ...)
    fig1.colorbar(img)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I solved problem using eyllanesc comment